# launchctl issues: Bootstrap failed: 5: Input/output error

Tags: launchd

Before Big Sur I was able to use launchtl like this:

plst file:

Label
    com.iPinky7.removeLogs
    Program
    /Users/michael/Downloads/Python/scripts/removeLogs.sh
    ProgramArguments
    
        commandLineArgument
    
    StartCalendarInterval
    
        Hour
        0
        Minute
        0
    
    StandardErrorPath
    /Users/michael/Downloads/Python/scripts/removeLogsErr.log
    StandardOutPath
    /Users/michael/Downloads/Python/scripts/removeLogs.log

commands:
// load the LaunchAgent
launchctl bootstrap gui/501 com.cronjob1.plist
// immediately start the LaunchAgent
launchctl kickstart -k gui/501/com.cronjob1
// unload the LaunchAgent
launchctl bootout gui/501 com.cronjob1.plist

now I get errors I have no clue about:
Bootstrap failed: 5: Input/output error

can anyone help?